# Stack smashing detected on casting

Tags: c, struct, casting, stack

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c, d, e, f;
}
type1;

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c;
}
type2;

type1 RTE = {
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
};

void copy(type1 * arg) {
  * arg = RTE;
}
int main() {
  // Write C code here
  printf("%d\n", RTE.c);
  type2 local;
  copy((type1 * ) &local);
  printf("%d", local.c);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get a stack smashing detected error. I suspect it is because of the cast but I can't figure out why. I would be grateful if someone could explain me.

Comment: Copying 6 ints into the space for 3 seems like a bad idea.

Comment: You can't see why trying to force a 6-element structure into a 3-element structure is a problem?  You're writing past the end of the structure.  Of course you're having problems.  At your level of understanding, you should not be using type casts with pointers.  You're only going to get yourself into trouble.  All you're doing is masking compile-time bugs, and instead getting runtime errors.

Comment: So there s no way to copy just the first 3 elements of the structure with the 6 elements into the smaller one?

Comment: Yes, but not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure `type1` will require double the space in memory required by `type2`, but you’ve only allocated a variable of `type2` in statement `type2 local;`.  This would have been allocated on the stack, since it is a local variable.  When the pointer is cast in statement `copy((type1 * ) &local);`then dereferenced in statement `* arg = RTE;` inside of function `copy`, the program will copy the larger contents of `RTE` into the smaller allocated memory of `local` basically overflowing.  If the stack fills from the bottom up, this would basically corrupt the stack causing failure when the program returns.

As a general practice it is not a good idea to cast between two different types of pointers.  Also, for ANSI C the compiler may determine how to arrange `struct` members relative to the base address for the `struct`, so it is not safe to assume any particular member of the `struct` will be transferred any other particular member, regardless of type and definition order.

If you want to copy the contents of an object of `type1` into an object of `type2`, it should be done member by member.

Comment: But something like that would be safe? I see that it works: #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c, d, e, f;
}
type1;

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c;
}
type2;

type1 RTE = {
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
};
type2 local;
void copy(type1 * arg) {
  * arg = RTE;
}
int main() {
  // Write C code here
  printf("%d\n", RTE.c);
  copy((type1 * ) &local);
  printf("%d", ((type1*) &local)->f);

  return 0;
}

Comment: When I mention copy member by member I mean that you would have to change the parameter from type1 * arg to type2 * arg, then copy members using arg->a = RTE.a;, arg->b = RTE.b;, etc.

Comment: But why if I declare it as a global variable it works and local variable doesn't?

Comment: In the case of the local variable, you are corrupting the stack, which stores the return address from the copy function.  The global variable will be assigned its own memory in RAM and you are probably just overflowing into some unused memory.  In some cases the program will throw an exception in this case, but it really just depends on how the compiler arranges things in memory.  Even though it works in this case, be aware that this is a bad practice and changing machines, tool chain or maybe just the next time you run the program you cannot be sure to get the same result.